# Is it possible to add a hidden value to every item of qlistWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, hidden-field, qlistwidgetitem

Is it possible to add hidden value to every item of `qlistWidget`.
I get data from the database and add it to `qlistWidget`.

[image]

I want to assign the `id` of every row as hidden data to every item in `qlistWidget` to use it in the future, like the HTML tag `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="15" />`.

The following is the code that get the data from database.

```
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
qry.exec();
while(qry.next()){
     ui->listWidget->addItem(qry.value("username").toString());
}
```

**Is it possible to do that ?**

Comment: [There probably is a way.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html#setData).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Thank you, but can you please give me an example, about use this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use setData() and data(). Example:

```
// set data
auto *item = new QListWidgetItem(qry.value("username").toString());
QVariant v;
v.setValue(qry.value("id").toInt());
item->setData(Qt::UserRole, v);
ui->listWidget->addItem(item);

// get back the data
QVariant v = item->data(Qt::UserRole);
int id = v.value<int>();
```

Comment: Please answer on my other question, It is relevant to this question, If you can. [How can fetch the row which has been recently added in the qlistwidget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459584/how-can-fetch-the-row-which-has-been-recently-added-in-the-qlistwidget)

Answer (score 1):

Create your own class which inherits from QListWidgetItem, and the data you want to hide will be a member of your class.

Comment: Thanks, but I want a quick way.

Comment: I prefer this way. Since, `setData` adds an extra empty space before the widgetlist item. I experienced this with PyQt. I only added a wrapper class that extends QListWidgetItem class. `class CustomListWidgetItem(QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, listWidget, identifier):
        super(CustomListWidgetItem, self).__init__(listWidget)
        self.id = identifier`