# How can fetch the row which has been recently added in the qlistwidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistwidget

How to fetch the last inserted item.

An example

```
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
qry.exec();
while(qry.next()){
   ui->listWidget->addItem(qry.value("username").toString());
}
```

As you seen in the previous example specifically this line `ui->listWidget->addItem(qry.value("username").toString());`

This line to add every database row in as an item in qlistwidget.

I have tried to use the following but does not work .

```
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
qry.exec();
while(qry.next()){
   ui->listWidget->addItem(qry.value("username").toString());
   ui->listWidget->currentItem()->setData(Qt::UserRole, qry.value("id").toString());
}
```

I want to get last inserted item, to apply the `setData()` method, on each item was added.

---

**Edit**

I have an error, when delete an item Deletes the item that before.

[image]

What is the problem in the following code:

```
ui->listWidget->takeItem(ui->listWidget->row(ui->listWidget->currentItem()));
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=:id");
qry.bindValue(":id",ui->listWidget->currentItem()->data(Qt::UserRole).toString());
if(qry.exec()){
     qDebug()<< "Ok";
}else{
     qDebug()<< "Errro";
}
```

Comment: Deleted my answer because it seems I misunderstood your question as retrieving the last database element, rather than the last GUI element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do next (it is just example) Your code doesn't work because currentItem() return item selected by user or by programmer, but you don't provide selection, so this code doesn't work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{//this code works because
    ui->listWidget->addItem(QString::number(i));//here you add item to the end
    //here you use last item by count()-1
    ui->listWidget->item(ui->listWidget->count()-1)->setData(Qt::UserRole, "id"+QString::number(i));//set data to last item
}
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    qDebug() << ui->listWidget->item(i)->data(Qt::UserRole).toString();
}
```

Output:

```
"id0" 
"id1" 
"id2" 
"id3" 
"id4" 
"id5" 
"id6" 
"id7" 
"id8" 
"id9"
```

This code works identical but it is really bad approach

```
ui->listWidget->setCurrentItem(ui->listWidget->item(ui->listWidget->count()-1));
ui->listWidget->currentItem()->setData(Qt::UserRole, "id"+QString::number(i));
```

Edit:

First of all takeItem remove item from widget but doesn't delete it from memory. So if you don't want get memory leak you should use delete, gor example

```
delete ui->listWidget->takeItem(ui->listWidget->row(ui->listWidget->currentItem()));
```

Back to your problem. Try firstly delete data in database and after that delete it from widget. Something like this

```
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=:id");
//qDebug() << ui->listWidget->currentItem()->data(Qt::UserRole).toString();//now you can see id which you want to delete
    qry.bindValue(":id",ui->listWidget->currentItem()->data(Qt::UserRole).toString());//make sure that margin id in your app is relly margin id in your database
    if(qry.exec()){
         qDebug()<< "Ok";
    }else{
         qDebug()<< "Errro";
}

delete ui->listWidget->takeItem(ui->listWidget->row(ui->listWidget->currentItem()));
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code does not delete the selected item, but delete the previous item.

Comment: @LionKing Excuse me, but I don't understand you. Do you want add item and after that delete it?

Comment: I mean when click on an item to delete it, the item that will be deleted is the previous item of the selected item.

Comment: @LionKing, you mark my answer as accepted, so it means that I was right and you solve this problem?

Comment: @LionKing in this case, can you also vote up my answer please? Thank you too.

Answer (score 2):

You should create QListWidgetItem separately and operate on it.

```
while(qry.next()){
   auto *item = new QListWidgetItem(qry.value("username").toString());
   item->setData(Qt::UserRole, qry.value("id").toString());
   ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
}
```